# Android Google wallet FullWalletRequest returns Error 404 (Invalid parameters)

Tags: android, android-pay

So I've been trying to integrate Google Wallet API in My app. I have Used [this tutorial](https://io2014codelabs.appspot.com/static/codelabs/instant-buy/#1). But at requesting full mask phase in `OnActivityResult` returned request code is 404. I have updated google play services to `version 8.4.0` but now Android pay does not support Android versions below 4.4 . Is there something I am missing here? I need to make it work on android 4.0+.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the tutorial is not up-to-date and Google Wallet is replaced by Android Pay now. I suggest you look at the new tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/android-pay/android/tutorial

I can't give much suggestions without source code but make sure that you use either `WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST` or `WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION` (as `WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX` is now deprecated). Also all the parameters you send to `PaymentMethodTokenizationParameters`, `MaskedWalletRequest` and `FullWalletRequest` are correct. Error code 404 is usually caused by wrong parameters: [ERROR_CODE_INVALID_PARAMETERS](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/WalletConstants.html#constants).